# MAX MIN date ranges for MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, joomla

This is using Joomla database class but hopefully this makes sense. I need to return the max date and min date depending on certain date range. The problem I am having is, I also need the version_id for each of those dates. The query I have written is returning the version of the max date value only. What I would like to end up with is the version id of the min date and the min date value as well as the version id of the max date and the max date value. I think it might be a case for union but I'm not sure how.

```
$query->select('a.ucm_type_id, a.ucm_item_id, a.version_id, MIN(a.save_date), MAX(a.save_date)')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__ucm_history') . ' AS a')
    ->where('a.save_date BETWEEN ' . $db->quote($from_date) . ' AND ' . $db->quote($to_date))
    ->where('a.ucm_type_id IN (' . implode(',',$db->quote($content_type_ids)) . ')')
    ->group(array('a.ucm_type_id', 'a.ucm_item_id', ));
    // Join over the users for the checked out user.
    $query->select('b.type_title AS type')
    ->join('LEFT', '#__content_types AS b ON b.type_id=a.ucm_type_id');

    $db->setQuery($query);
```

Comment: Figure out the query first. Then worry about how to re-engineer to fit joomla

Comment: That was my plan, The query as written there works in Joomla but it's not the right query. That's what I need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query would only comply with the sql standard if `version_id` field were functionally dependent on `ucm_type_id` and `ucm_item_id`. MySQL under certain sql mode setting allows queries like go through, which may lead to some nasty suprises because the value of the `version_id` is indeterminate. Fortunatley, in the recent mysql versions this mode is turned off by default.

You need to get the max and min dates within the date range in a subquery and join this back on your original table to get other fields associated with these dates.

In sql your query will look sg like the following:

```
select a.ucm_type_id,
       a.ucm_item_id,
       a.version_id,
       a.save_date,
       if(a.save_date=t1.min_save_date, 'min','max') as min_or_max,
       b.type_title AS type 
from `#__ucm_history` a
inner join
    (select `ucm_type_id`, `ucm_item_id`, MIN(save_date) as min_save_date, MAX(save_date) as max_save_date
     from `#__ucm_history`
     where ucm_type_id IN (...)
           and save_date BETWEEN ... and ...
     group by `ucm_type_id`, `ucm_item_id`
    ) t1 on a.ucm_type_id=t1.ucm_type_id and a.ucm_item_id=t1.ucm_item_id
left join `#__content_types` AS b ON b.type_id=a.ucm_type_id
where a.save_date=t1.min_save_date or a.save_date=t1.max_save_date
```

Replace the `...` sections with your parameters coming from the php code.

Test and tweak your query in sql environment, and once you are happy with it, then implement it using your ORM tool. But my guess is that you will need to run it as a raw sql statement.

Comment: That works perfectly thank you! I have one more question, is it possible to only return if there is only a max AND a min? if there are two version_ids that share the same ucm_type and ucm_id?

Comment: If there is at least 1 record for an ucm_type_id, and ucm_item_id pair, then you will have both max and min. Max and min may be the same, but either both will be there, or none of them.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain that very well, is it possible to load it into the same object with: ucm_type_id, ucm_item_id, min_version_id, max_version_id, min_save_date, max_save_date?

Comment: It is possible, join `#__ucm_history` table **twice** on `t1` subuery, once using min_save_date, the other time using max_save_date (obviously, use the 2 id columns in the joins as well).

Comment: Im sorry mate, I have tried a number of ways and just can't get it. Can I bother you to write a second answer showing me what you mean please?